# Bundler json locked

Tags: ruby, bundler

```
You have requested:
  json >= 0

The bundle currently has json locked at 1.5.1.
Try running `bundle update json`
```

What's the problem?

For the record, if I do try bundle update json, it complains about do_jdbc being locked at 0.10.5 and me requesting >= 0, and if I try updating do_jdbc, I get the exact same message suggesting I update do_jdbc.

Strangely, a different user with the exact same setup on the same machine working in same shared directory gets no such error.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your Gemfile.lock file and running `bundle`?

Comment: I rvm imploded and reinstalled several times, eventually it just stopped doing this. No idea why.

Comment: @hsiu, then you should add that last comment as an answer to the question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
bundle update json do_jdbc
```

to update both simultaneously.